# IllegalArgumentException in kotlin while trying to build audio plaback capture recorder - "Unknown mixing rule type"

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make an app that records the audio being played on your device and ran into an error while generating the audio record object required for it.

I have tried what I could find on the internet but the problem has not been resolved and there also seems to be very little documentation on the topic.

Here's my code:

```kotlin
class AudioPlaybackRecorderService : Service() {
    private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager
    private lateinit var notificationChannel: NotificationChannel
    private lateinit var notification: Notification

    private lateinit var mediaProjectionManager: MediaProjectionManager;
    private lateinit var audioPlaybackCapConfig: AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration
    private lateinit var audioFormat: AudioFormat
    private lateinit var audioRecord: AudioRecord

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("foregroundNotificationChannel", "foreNifChannel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

        notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannel.id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("Usb Audio")
            .setContentText("App running in foreground")
            .build()

        startForeground(startId, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION)


        mediaProjectionManager = getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager

        audioPlaybackCapConfig = AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder(mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(
            intent!!.getIntExtra("resCode", 120),
            intent!!.extras!!["data"] as Intent
        )).build()

        audioFormat = AudioFormat.Builder()
            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_MP3)
            .setSampleRate(44100)
            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
            .build()

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            audioRecord = AudioRecord.Builder()
                .setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig(audioPlaybackCapConfig)
                .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
                .setBufferSizeInBytes(20)
                .build()
        }


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

I'm passing the data to the service like this:

```kotlin
    val serviceIntent = Intent(this, AudioPlaybackRecorderService::class.java)
                        serviceIntent.putExtra("resCode", resultCode)
                        serviceIntent.putExtra("data", data)
                        startService(serviceIntent)
```

And here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.usbaudio.AudioPlaybackRecorderService@11bcb6e with Intent { cmp=com.example.usbaudio/.AudioPlaybackRecorderService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown mixing rule type
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4339)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:238)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1952)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7700)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown mixing rule type
    at android.media.audiopolicy.AudioMix$Builder.build(AudioMix.java:448)
    at android.media.AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.createAudioMix(AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.java:135)
    at android.media.AudioRecord$Builder.buildAudioPlaybackCaptureRecord(AudioRecord.java:688)
    at android.media.AudioRecord$Builder.build(AudioRecord.java:716)
    at com.example.usbaudio.AudioPlaybackRecorderService.onStartCommand(AudioPlaybackRecorderService.kt:66)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4321)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:238) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1952) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7700) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Same issue, not much documentation

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `addMatchingUsage` or `excludeUsage` on the `AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration` object. This is described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/av-capture#usage). Use something like

```
AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder(mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(
        intent!!.getIntExtra("resCode", 120),
        intent!!.extras!!["data"] as Intent
    )).addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).build()
```